# Getting the error message : "The map coordinate system is not supported by this service" in Map store

Tags: geoserver

I am getting the message

> The map coordinate system is not supported by this service

when trying to add new raster image from WMS though GeoServer online service which I can access it.

I am unable to add any raster from my WMS GeoServer.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: which coordinate system are you trying to use?